# List of tuples of multiple elements to plain list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Need to read from a file many random-generated numbers and insert them into a plain list: how to do in the easy way?

example of file:

14, 64, 1, 0, 435, 5

4, 7, 2532, 6, 11, 88

...

using the code

```
rows = file.read()
splitted = rows.split(",")
print(splitted)
```

I get the result

```
['14', '64', '1', '0', '435', '5\n4', '7', '2532', '6\n11', '88']
```

but I'd like to get them cleaned and converted to int:

```
[14, 64, 1, 0, 435, 5, 4, 7, 2532, 6, 11, 88]
```

any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example to lead the file:

```
out = []
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for row in f_in:
        # skip empty lines (if any):
        if not row.strip():
            continue
        out.extend(map(int, row.split(',')))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[14, 64, 1, 0, 435, 5, 4, 7, 2532, 6, 11, 88]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
out = np.loadtxt('datatxt.txt', dtype=int, delimiter=',').ravel()
```

This gives your wanted array in a flattened form. If you need to convert it to list:

```
out = out.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of `'\n'` reading file line by line:

```
splitted = []

with open('file') as file:
    for l in file:
        splitted.append([int(x) for x in l.split(",")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('your_file_name.txt') as f:
    s=f.read()

s=s.replace('\n', ',')

res=s.split(',')

res=[int(i) for i in res if len(i)>0]
```